# Slick.js - Pause slideshow after it loops back to first slide

Tags: jquery

I'm using the slick.js slideshow library and I'm trying to basically pause the slideshow after it loops back to the first slide. I know I have to do something with the "slickCurrentSlide" and "slickPause" methods. But I can't seem to get it to work. Thanks!!!

```
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div><img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="bg1" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="bg2" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/bg3.jpg" alt="bg3" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/bg4.jpg" alt="bg4" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/bg5.jpg" alt="bg5" /></div>
    </div>


      var currentSlide = $('.slideshow').slick('slickCurrentSlide');

    $('.slideshow').on('beforeChange', function pauseSlideShow(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

      console.log("this is slide #" + currentSlide);

        setTimeout(function() {
          if (nextSlide === 0) {
            console.log("Yay!!! we're back to 1");
            $('.slideshow').slickPause(); 
          };
        }, 3000);

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

This will pause the slideshow if the slide ends up back on the first slide, whether through autoplay, swiping or using prev/next controls.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/55eow2ft/

```
var $slider = $(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: true
})
.on('afterChange', function( e, slick, currentSlide ) {
    if( currentSlide == 0 ) {
        $slider.slick('slickPause');
        console.log('paused');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this. I realized a few days ago that if the user tries to click on the dots after the slide stops autoplaying, those dots are no longer clickable. Do you know how to fix this. Thanks again for your help a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Thank you so so so much. That worked. I was writing the 'afterChange' function a bit differently and it was causing an issue after it paused. You're the best!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Slick's `onAfterChange` callback.

```
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slide: 'div',
  cssEase: 'linear',
  onAfterChange: function(slider){
    if(slider.currentSlide === 0){
      $('.slider').slickPause();
    };
  }
});
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/14d6qn65/2/)

Comment: As of version 1.4.1, Slick callback methods have been deprecated in favor of events.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise.